# All this for the low price of

Tags: grammar

I want to list several features of a product and then at the end I want to finish with:

`all this just for the minimum price` or `all this for the minimum price`

My best attempt was `获得这一切只需要最低的价格`.

Which is kind of similar to something like:

`all this for just $29.99`

or

`all this for only $29.99`

or equally

`all this just for the minimum price of $29.99`

I use the term 'minimum price' in my sentence because it makes sense in it's context.

I'd be interested in the Chinese version of the first sentence most importantly, but versions of all the others would be interesting as well.

I guess the title for this could also be `all this for just/just for..`

EDIT: If `all this just for the minimum price` seems weird then simply add the price on the end `all this just for the minimum price of $2.99`.

Comment: A lot of the answers are very formal to the point of feeling like a written statement rather than a sales-pitch from a salesperson. I think this context is a lot more colloquial. But then again, I have never heard anybody say "all this just for the *minimum* price" in any setting ever, and I've lived in two different English speaking countries and English is my native tongue. 

Colloquially (in Beijing at least), the term 就 is often used to convey the feeling of "only" as in 这一切就29块钱 or 全部就29块钱 (or if you really want to include the cents, 全部就29快99). You can think of it as replacing 只有/只需要.

Comment: @Marko I explained the use of the term 'minimum price' below. If you imagine something like a product on Envato where a specific minimum price is generally well known within the context of that platform, or possibly a platform where the minimum price is known but different in each country - like the play store. Yeah you can't really use 就 in a formal setting like selling a product. The 仅需底价 in the chosen answer below is very good. The other answers don't attempt to answer the question whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

最低$29.99，以上（功能/产品/blank/etc）全带走～ is an accurate, lively translation.
To be more formal: 包干最低$29.99。

EDIT1：

I see what you mean after reading the comments, then it shulould be:

全•部•底•价！（no more, no less translation）（and certainly understandable by those who know the term 'minimum price'）（and • is for emphasis i.e. 'just'）

均仅以底价出售（elaborate it a bit）

EDIT2：

Arrh, how tricky! Examine more a bit, I found that you are trying to say something, with all these awesome functions, is on sale at just the minimum price!

Then I would say:

仅需底价，全部享有！

comment: 获得这一切只需要最低的价格 is too wordy, and doen't fully convey the implication that how favorable, how rare chance the price is for such a multifunctional product, plus the specific term 'minimum price'.

1. 获得这一切 is plain. 享有 conveys the benefits of having it.
2. 只需要 can be shortened to 仅需.
3. 的 in a proper noun or specific term in Chinese is usually avoided.

Comment: I think we are all a bit neglectful or arrogant for we answer the question without carefully reading it, as in this case the context is provided in the very first sentence, assuming the op is poor in Chinese, and just casually toss an answer, 'outsmarting' the op.

Comment: This is the first answer to actually translate one or more of my sentences! It's a good translation too. I'm not poor in Chinese, and my gf IS Chinese but that was the best we could come up with together. Although she doesn't exactly speak English and she said I should have removed 的 too. She removed it from my previous attempts but I'm used to using it since my Chinese is conversational. I don't like `以上` that much because it doesn't emphasise 'all', as you say, we need to emphasise you get all the above benefits. I guess `获得这一切只需要最低价格` is not too bad without the 的, but yours is nicer.

Comment: I guess the context of 'minimum price' wasn't clear for some people. If you imagine something like a product on Envato where a specific minimum price is generally well known within the context of that platform.

Comment: You're right the sentence is tricky to translate though, I guess that's why we've got two answers with zero useful content and yours finally has an answer after two edits..not to mention I and my Chinese gf had a lot of trouble coming up with what we did.

Answer (score 2):

`获得这一切只需要最低的价格` sounds very unnatural. you can simply say `只要$29.99` or `只需$29.99`) which contains the meaning of minimum price without mentioning it. To be clear about "all this", I think you can use `以上`(all above) or `以下` (all below) or `全部`(all)

If your Chinese version referring to Chinese currency, the dollar sign is ¥.

Comment: Ok but what's your whole sentence? I know how to translate individual parts like you have but it's putting the whole sentence together which is difficult. Please leave a complete answer.

Comment: @Hasen Your original sentence "all this for..." is not a complete sentence either. The best suggestion is the one proposed by this answer. However, don't use 以上 or 以下. Instead, 这些 or 全部 or 全都 are all natural options for “all this”.

Comment: No idea what you're looking at...my original sentence is `all this just for the minimum price` and is clearly highlighted...which is obviously a complete sentence.

Comment: Your translation `只要$29.99` is a translation of `only $29.99` which is nice, but I obviously already knew how to translate such a simple thing and it's not what I asked. Your answer would be better suited as a comment rather than an answer since you're just suggesting translations for parts of my sentence only.

Comment: Even if it wasn't a complete sentence, you still can't translate something different, or just parts of it. I saw some people posted how to say 'for all I know' in Chinese, I'm sure you'll agree it would not be acceptable to post an answer as '我知道' because it's not what they asked for. The meaning of a whole sentence can often be very different to the parts that make it up.

Comment: So many problems with your answer...$29.99 also does NOT contain the meaning "minimum price"..it's a very specific price. What if the minimum price is different depending on which country the person reading it is in? A chinese person reads it in the USA, or a Chinese person reads it in mainland China or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

"minimum price" implies "from +(price)" e.g. "from $29.99"

> "All this for the low price of..."  should be translated as the following:

- "All this" = "全部一起"
- "(selling) for the low price of (*actual price*)" = "以 (*actual price*) 低價 (出售)" or "以 低價(*actual price*) (出售)"

> "All this for the low price of $29.99" = "全部一起 以 $29.99 低價 出售" or "全部一起 以  低價 $29.99 出售"

Example with an extended sentence:

> 一套十二把廚刀，加十四吋實木砧板， 全部一起 以 $129.99 (超)低價 出售"
>
> A set of twelve kitchen knives, plus 14 inches solid wood cutting board. All this for the (super) low price of $129.99

Answer (score -1):

Today we have a special discount: all 5 products for only 5 yuan.
今天我们有促销活动：五件商品只需要五元。

Don't much like this English: all this for the minimum price so I wouldn't translate it.

But this is translateable:

all this for just $29.99
所有的这些只要二十九点九九美元

Comment: So how would you translate my actual first sentence?

Comment: I explained in my answer that 'minimum price' makes sense in the context I'm using it in. Imagine a platform where there is a clear minimum price for things. Like for example everyone knows the minimum price is $9.99 or whatever. Like an mp3 store with a known minimum price.

Comment: If you really didn't like the English of my sentence then you could have translated `all this for the minimum price of $4.99` instead. If you don't like that the minimum price is known in my sentence, then just add it on the end. Your sentence is a quite different one. I also gave other examples sentences that could be translated. Really not sure why you've just translated your own sentence instead.